# CSS Constant Transition Speed

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition, css-transforms

I'm trying to achieve a constant transition speed.

Note, I don't mean the difference between "ease" and "linear". What I mean is if we go from 0px to 20px it will take 1 second, but going from 0 to 100px should take 10 seconds.

```
.box {
    width: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: width 1s linear;
}
```

Can't seem to find a way to do this. And all my searches just turn up ease/linear differences.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found is using custom properties. In the following example, I'm using `20` to represent one unit of width. When multiplied by `.05` we get `1`, or a single second. Using a custom property, we can override the `transition-width` variable to a desired pixel length. The calculation will update dynamically and adjust the `transition-duration` accordingly.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('.box.one').classList.add('start');
  document.querySelector('.box.two').classList.add('start');
}, 0);
```

```css
.box {
  --transition-width: 20;
  --transition-speed: .05;
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-duration: calc(var(--transition-width) * var(--transition-speed) * 1s);
  background: black;
}

.box.one.start {
  width: 20px;
}

.box.two.start {
  --transition-width: 100;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box one"></div>
<div class="box two"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr0x5sk7/1/)

Comment: Nice, simple solution I was looking for, thx!